# Raygun client unable to send - failed resolution of InetAddressUtils

Tags: android, raygun, raygun.io

Is anyone who is using Raygun in their Android apps seeing this error exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/conn/util/InetAddressUtils;
    at main.java.com.mindscapehq.android.raygun4android.messages.NetworkInfo.readIPAddress(SourceFile:117)
    at main.java.com.mindscapehq.android.raygun4android.messages.NetworkInfo.<init>(SourceFile:20)
    at main.java.com.mindscapehq.android.raygun4android.messages.RaygunMessageDetails.setNetworkInfo(SourceFile:61)
    at main.java.com.mindscapehq.android.raygun4android.RaygunMessageBuilder.setNetworkInfo(SourceFile:81)
    at main.java.com.mindscapehq.android.raygun4android.RaygunClient.buildMessage(SourceFile:508)
    at main.java.com.mindscapehq.android.raygun4android.RaygunClient.send(SourceFile:221)
```

This exception is very intermittent, but when it does happen, it always occurs when the app calls RaygunClient.send(...). I'm using Raygun in my app to report error conditions such as a failed webservice call, however, when I report this to Raygun it crashes my app!

Comment: I suspect this could be a legacy http apache library issue. See issue I raised with Raygun here https://raygun.com/forums/thread/145090#145089

Answer (score 0):

The release of v3.0.6 includes fixes that address the problems seen with InetAddressUtils NoClassDefFoundError exceptions. Please update to release v3.0.6 and let us know if the problems persist.

Please see our documentation on how to update. https://raygun.com/documentation/language-guides/android/crash-reporting/installation/

Regards,
Mitchell.